# intent setFlags FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

Tags: android, android-intent

On Android, I started 4 activities A, B, C, D, if I want to go back from D to A, I can use 'intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)'. But if the activities are same class activities opened as follows, How can I go back from D to A now?

```
Intent i = new Intent(FlagsTest.this, FlagsTest.class);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: have u tried any answer ??

Answer (score 3):

You can start any activity you want like this to bring them to front :
To go back from D to A do something like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, A.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Use this Tutorial It will Help U [LINK](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/5eb400434e2c35f4)

Comment: I kown this way to go back skip pages, but if 'this' is same class with 'Class', it not work.

Comment: please explain more properly

Answer (score 1):

**Try This way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

**1.write this code on master activity or application activity**.

```
private KillReceiver clearActivityStack;

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    clearActivityStack = new KillReceiver();
    registerReceiver(clearActivityStack, IntentFilter.create("clearStackActivity", "text/plain"));
   // register to clear stack
}

private final class KillReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        finish();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(clearActivityStack); // unregister to clear stack
}
```

**2.write this code before start A Activity**

```
 Intent intent = new Intent("clearStackActivity");
 intent.setType("text/plain");
 sendBroadcast(intent);
```

**3.start your activity**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```