# Intent flags to Login page redirect, killing previous Activities

Tags: android, android-intent

Basically I have a `Service` that at some points it will sync with the network in order to check if the token is still valid. if it isn't, it should redirect to the login screen (**from the service)** and if the user press the **back button, it should NOT show the previous Activity but instead exit the app.**

I'm not asking how to hack `onBackPressed`, I already know how to do it. I'm asking how to accomplish this using the intent flags.

So far I have tried the following:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Using the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` is mandatory because I'm calling `startActivity()` from a service (or at least thrown exception told me so), and using `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` cause it was supposed to remove all previous activities from the stack, leaving only the new one.

The issue is if I press back, I am still able to go to the previous `Activity`, which makes me think the combination of both flags are *clearing the activities in the NEW task, not in the previous one*

I might be wrong on the reason, but it doesn't work. Any help will be appreciated, thanks

Comment: try this -->android.os.process.killprocess(android.os.process.mypid())

Comment: Check out my ans here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18633987/intent-setflags-flag-activity-clear-top/18634598#18634598

Answer (score 1):

You need to add one more Flag in your `Intent` which is `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY` to enable your activity to be the start of new task of your application

from [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html):

```
If set, this activity will become the start of a new task on this history stack.
```

**sample:**

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.addFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
```

Make sure that you use `addFlags` to add 2 flags in your intent