# Android App directly close from any activity

Tags: android

I want to directly close the Android Application from any Sub-Activity, 
and when user can start app again, at that time, app should start in Main Activity , not in Sub-Activity.
I used one method: moveTaskToBack(true);

but i can't retrieve successful result.

Help Me.

Thanks.

Comment: System.exit in android app? Seriously? Finish your activity (and all activities that u need closed) by calling activity.finish() when needed. All next fires from this app via launcher will kick start it again a fresh.

Comment: Check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18633987/intent-setflags-flag-activity-clear-top/18634598#18634598

Comment: Thanks. , I already used System.exit(0) mehtod, but it only finish current activity, not application.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226495/android-exit-application-code

Comment: android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
super.onDestroy();

Comment: Activity.finish(); method is close current activity, not application, I want to stop application from sub-activity.

Comment: Best way is whenever you open Sub-activity with intent use finish it will finish the Previous activity

Answer (score 0):

you can use Sysetm.exit(0) in on pause method

```
  @Override
  public void onPause() {

  super.onPause();  // Always call the superclass method first
  System.exit(0);
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT  > Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
 else
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | IntentCompat.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(i);
```